# Why webrtc peer gets empty event.streams array in `track` event?

Tags: webrtc

When a remote in webrtc connection (javascript) calls removeTrack() and the addTrack(), then local peer gets `track(event)` event with `event.streams.length === 0`.
So, I can not set `videoTag.srcObject` to `event.streams[0]`.
I have to construct the new MediaStream object manually and assign it to `srcObject`:

```
let streamToAdd;
if (event.streams.length === 0)
    streamToAdd = new MediaStream([addedTrack]);
else
    streamToAdd = event.streams[0];


userAV.video.srcObject = streamToAdd; //// instead of event.streams[0];
```

My questions are:

1. Is it correct, that the local peer gets empty streams[] array ?
2. Should I create the new MediaStreamObject as shown above or another approach is recommended ?

Comment: This depends on how you call addTrack on the corresponding peer. If you do not call it with a mediastream as second argument then this is expected.